# Viewer Materials (wrong conversion from Revit shaded view)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm working on a Revit Mechanical Model (Duct, Pipes and Cable Trays).
I setup a Shaded view in Revit with a custom color scheme (organized applying different material to each System Type). The graphics is clean and works.

When we translate the Model to the Forge platform, the result is a wrong color scheme in the Viewer. It looks like the fittings got wrong material after model translation.

In this picture you can see:
 - on the left, the Revit Model view (shaded style),
 - on the right, the Forge Viewer with wrong colors.

[image: image: RevitView to ForgeViewer]

We tried with different models but the problem is always the same. is this a bug? anyone got this kind of issue?

Comment: how this fits with site rules? have you consider reading how to ask question?

Comment: do you have a small sample file to share? if so, please send to forge.help[at]autodesk.com (please do not send confidential information)